# Wi-Fi-enable a USB hard drive

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, external-hard-drive

I have a "smart picture frame" type of device that displays media files from a connected USB hard drive.

I wonder if it is possible to stream some files to this hard drive via my home network by plugging a Wi-Fi dongle into the drive. On eBay and Amazon I found Wi-Fi dongles that enable any network-connected device to stream content *from* an external hard drive, but I want to stream content *to* that device.

Are there any USB devices that turn my drive into one that I can access on my network to put data on it?

Comment: I took the liberty of editing this Question to clarify what I *think* OP is asking.

Answer (score 0):

A typical USB hard drive is designed to be a dumb peripheral controlled by a USB host; it's not designed to have peripherals of its own; it's not designed to control a USB Wi-Fi dongle.

A small device that acts as a standalone file server on a network is often called a "Network Attached Storage" or NAS box. The [TP-Link TL-WR710n](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00FRMAOIO) appears to be a cheap device that can act as a Wi-Fi NAS box that you can plug a USB hard drive into. However, the USB hard drive will become a peripheral of the TP-Link box; it won't be directly attached to your "smart picture frame" display. So this solution would only work for you if your "smart picture frame" type display also has a way to connect to a network and access media files on a file server on the network.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however the frame itself isn´t smart in the sense of able to access a network (as we know from TV or similar). If I understand you correct I still have to connect my device to the file-server, which I doubt it can handle.